# Does Kotlin permit extension methods on lambdas?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm trying to make a nice SAM-like API for instantiating abstract classes because I don't like object expressions. I'm trying to do something like:

```
{my lambda code here}.my_extension_function()
```

Is this possible with Kotlin?

Comment: you can't instantiate abstract classes :p

Comment: Note: just because you can do this (as per Sergey's answer), doesn't mean it's a good idea.  For one thing, it's likely to confuse most people who read your code; and (as per the issue with semicolons that Sergey mentioned) it's likely to have some unexpected effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The sample code is:

```
// extension function on lambda with generic parameter
fun <T> ((T) -> Unit).my_extension_function() {
    // ...
}

// extension function on lambda without generic parameter
fun (() -> Unit).my_extension_function() {
    // ...
}
```

And use it, for example, like this:

```
// lambda variable with generic parameter
val lambda: (Int) -> Unit = {
    // 'it' contains Int value
    //...
}

// lambda variable without generic parameter
val lambda: () -> Unit = {
    //...
}

lambda.my_extension_function()

// also we can call extension function on lambda without generic parameter like this
{
    //...
}.my_extension_function()

// or with generic parameter
{ i: Int ->
        //...
}.my_extension_function()
```

**Note:** if you call extension function on lambda without creating a variable and there is a function call before it you need to add **semicolon** after function call, e.g.:

```
someFunction();

{
    //...
}.my_extension_function()
```